# How do I write point clouds (.ply) to image (.jpg) in python?

Tags: python, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I am completely new to working with point cloud data. Right now I have a ".ply" file and its corresponding ".bmp" file. Both of them were generated from a TOF camera.
I am trying to get a ".jpg" file by superimposing the depth data on the BMP file, but i am ffailing miserably.
I have tried using the open3d library for this purpose. But it does not work on google colab. Therefore I am looking for a solution in the python-pcl library (or any other library)
how can I achieve this?